# Solve $\int{x \sqrt{x-1}} dx$ using u-sub

Tags: calculus

I have a worksheet that says the following can be solved using a u-sub. I can solve it using parts, but I have no idea how to go about using substitution?

$\int{x \sqrt{x-1}} dx$

please help.

Comment: Let $u = x-1 $.

Comment: What's a  `u-sub`?

Comment: @Bernard Assuming you're not being sarcastic, I believe it's where you solve the integral using the change of variable $u=f(x)$

Comment: Didn't know that. And if the new variable is $t$, is it a t-sub? ;o)

Comment: Yes, you can prove this to be true for the entire alphabet

Comment: @mrnovice you sir are hilarious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I = \int x\sqrt{x-1} dx$

Let $u = \sqrt{x-1} \implies u^2+1=x$

$\implies du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}dx = \frac{1}{2u}dx$

Then $I = \int (u^2+1)u\cdot 2u  du$

$I = 2 \int u^4+u^2du$

Comment: Thank you for noting above that $u$-substitution can be generalized to any letter. It can also be proven to work outside of the Roman alphabet (see for reference the paper of Schmingus, Dingus *et alia*, "A mysterious discovery in the theory of integral calculus").

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $u=\sqrt{x-1}\implies x=u^2+1$ can you proceed from here?

Comment: if $u = \sqrt{x-1}$ then $du = \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^{-1/2} dx$ but that doesn't fit. I'm still confused.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky that's why I rewrote it as $x=u^2+1$ then $dx=2udu$ which is much easier. Either form works, just not solving for x makes it harder

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=u+1$ and $dx=du$ so that we get

$$I=\int(u+1)\sqrt u\ du=\int u^{3/2}+u^{1/2}\ du=\frac25u^{5/2}+\frac23u^{3/2}+c$$

and don't forget to set $u=x-1$ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is a nice way to deal with this kind of integrand.

When you want to evaluate integrals like $\int x\sqrt [n]{ax+b}\,dx$ set $u=\sqrt [n]{ax+b}$, raise $u$ to the $n$th power and then differentiate $u^n$ to get $du$.

Hence,
$$u=\sqrt [n]{ax+b},\quad u^n = ax+b, \quad \frac{u^n - b}a =x,\quad \frac {n\,u^{n-1}}a\,du = dx$$
which gives you the simplified integral
$$\begin{align}
\int \left(\frac{u^n - b}a\right) (u)\left( \frac {n\,u^{n-1}}a\right)\,du\;& =\;\frac n{a^2}\int u^{2n}-u^nb\,du\\
\end{align}$$

Integrate and substitute back into $x$-terms to get your final result.